# How can I limit the local storage maximum item?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm building github search app with github api in Angular. I need to limit the number of elements that local storage can take. If limit storage element number is more than 5, Add to Favorite button should not work or it can dissapear too. I did it with this `[ngStyle]="{'display': display.length > 5 && 'none' }"` but it's not exactly what I wanted. Here is the code:

**html:**

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="profile" (ngModelChange)="detectChange($event)" (keyup)="findProfile()" class="input">

  <ng-template [ngIf]="profile !== '' && user">
    <div class="profileContainer">
      <div class="leftDetails">
        <img class="userAvatar" [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="User Avatar">
        <div>
          <button class="button" [routerLink]="['', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]">View
            Profile</button>
          <button class="button" [ngStyle]="{'display': display.length > 5 && 'none' }" (click)="addLocal()">Add to
            Favorite</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rightDetails">
        <p><span>Username: </span> {{user.login}}</p>
        <p><span>Location:</span> {{user.location}}</p>
        <p><span>E-mail:</span> {{user.email}}</p>
        <p><span>Blog Link:</span> {{user.blog}}</p>
        <p><span>Member Since:</span> {{user.created_at}}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <div *ngIf="closeDiv">
    <div class="profileContainer" *ngFor="let item of display">
      <div class="leftDetails">
        <img class="userAvatar" [src]="item.avatar_url" alt="User Avatar">
        <div>
          <button class="button" [routerLink]="['', item.login.toLowerCase(), item.id ]">View Profile</button><br>
          <button class="button" (click)="removeLocal(item.id,item.storageKey)">Remove Favorite</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rightDetails">
        <p><span>Username:</span> {{item.login}}</p>
        <p><span>Location:</span> {{item.location}}</p>
        <p><span>E-Mail:</span> {{item.email}}</p>
        <p><span>Blog Link:</span> {{item.blog}}</p>
        <p><span>Member Since:</span> {{item.created_at}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="consoleLog()">CONSOLEEE</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**ts:**

```
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { bindCallback } from 'rxjs';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ArrayType } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  display: any;
  randomNumber: number;
  randomString: string;
  closeDiv: boolean = true;
  isClicked: boolean = true;

  constructor(private userData: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) =>
      JSON.parse(val)
    );
    console.log(this.display);
  }

  public findProfile() {
    this.userData.updateProfile(this.profile);
    this.userData.getUser().subscribe((result) => {
      this.user = result;
    });
  }

  public addLocal() {
    this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    this.randomString = this.randomNumber.toString();
    this.user.storageKey = this.randomString;
    localStorage.setItem(this.user.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.user));
    this.display = Object.values(localStorage).map((val: any) =>
      JSON.parse(val)
    );
  }

  public removeLocal(id: any, key: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.display.length; i++) {
      if (this.display[i].id === id) {
        this.display.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
      }
    }
  }

  public detectChange(ev: any) {
    ev.length > 0 ? (this.closeDiv = false) : (this.closeDiv = true);
  }
}
```

Comment: @pallavirichhariya I added the html codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel to use `map` over the localStorage, simply you can check the length of localstorage and add check on the HTML/template side.

```
this.display = Object.values(localStorage).length;
<button class="button" *ngIf="display.length < 5">Add to           
Favorite</button>
```

Comment: I think display is being used in html also for displaying the data , hence the map is used

Comment: @pallavirichhariya yes, you are right. I assigned another variable for the length.

Comment: @pallavirichhariya might be I was not aware of that use case :)